# Regaining Ubuntu Partition From Windows 7 which is inside LOGICAL PARTITION

Tags: partitioning

I've installed Ubuntu a long time ago , but after re-installing windows 7 , I haven't been able to use Ubuntu. Now I want to regain that hard drive space that Ubuntu was using. How do I remove my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7 and reuse the space?

An important point : The partition is inside the logical partition.The picture is given below :
http://postimage.org/image/4qg9i0dpp/

Comment: Please specify if you installed Ubuntu inside Windows, meaning via WUBI? Or you installed it on a separate partition, meaning dual boot? If you installed it in another partition, you simply need to remove the partition. Try [safely uninstall ubuntu inside windows](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) and [How to uninstall Ubuntu on dual boot Windows](http://bobmorris.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-on-dual-boot-windows-xp-using-windows-only/)

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu on a separate partition.

Comment: Did you try the links above? It isn't really a problem if it's a primary partition or logical partition. If you just want to regain the space, all you need is to delete the partition.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wubi FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

How do I manually uninstall Wubi?

Remove C:\ubuntu and C:\wubildr*

In Windows XP you need to edit C:\boot.ini and delete the Ubuntu/Wubi line. Alternatively you can modify the boot menu via Control Panel > System > Advanced > Startup and Recovery and pressing "Edit". For Windows 98 you have to edit C:\config.sys and remove the Wubi block. For Windows Vista/7, you can use the built-in bcdedit command or install EasyBCD to edit the boot menu. To use bcdedit, run cmd.exe as an administrator, then enter bcdedit to show all boot entries, note the {GUID} specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it: bcdedit /delete {GUID}

To remove Wubi from the add/remove list, delete the registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi

An easy method of removing this registry key is to paste the following text into a plain editor such as Notepad, close and save the file as something like removeWubiKey.reg (you may wish to go to Folder Options > View and disable the "Hide file extensions for known file types" option to check that the .reg extension has been applied correctly). Then you can perform the rest automatically by opening the file in the normal Windows manner, or choosing the "Merge" option from the right click context menu. Note: The formatting is rather strict, so copy the text exactly for best results. You may need to be logged in as the administrator to delete the key, depending on the version of Windows you are using. User Account Control in Vista may also ask for permission, in the typical fashion.

REGEDIT4

[-HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi]

After deleting the registry key, Ubuntu may still appear in the program list. If this is the case, you may be asked if you would like to remove the item from the list.